# Django user model, backward look up is not working

Tags: django, django-models

I've made a foreign key relationship with django User model, the forward lookup is working fine but when I try to backward is throwing this error:

> 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'urlpost_set'

I have also tried the related name! Also note that the Catagory to PostUrl and PostUrl to Catagory is working just fine!

My models.py:

```
from django.db import models

from django.contrib.auth.models import User


# Create your models here.
class Catagory(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=15, unique=True)
    created = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'catagory'


class UrlPost(models.Model):
    STATUS_CHOICES = (
        ('public', 'Public'),
        ('private', 'Private'),
    )
    profile = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='user_post', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    catagory = models.ForeignKey(Catagory, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
    url = models.URLField()
    status = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=STATUS_CHOICES, default='public')
    note = models.TextField(blank=True)
    created = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-created']
        verbose_name_plural = 'url Post'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have set `related_name='user_post'` while defining `ForeignKey` relation between your `User` model and `UrlPost`.

You have to use `.user_post.all()` instead of `.urlpost_set.all()` in your queryset.